# Handling camera functions in jpct

Tags: android, android-camera, jpct

I am working on android game. In this I am using JPCT framework. In this I want to use camera movement.As in some games the whole level view is viewed to the user( like in Angry Birds).
I am putiing my code in OnDraw() function.

```
@Override
 public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) 
 Camera cam = world.getCamera();
 cam.moveCamera(Camera.CAMERA_MOVELEFT,2);
```

Now, when this executes it continuously goes to the left. I want to use various camera functions like it goes left them zoom in on particular object then zoom out and then move right;something like that. How I would be able to do so??
I am very new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `cam.setPostion();` to position the camera at your desired coordinates. `cam.moveCamera()` is to move it continuously, like panning.

For the zooming part, you have to change the FOV of the camera. More the FOV, more you can see i.e zoomed out.